# Burn [knights-tour]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

> A knight's tour is a sequence of moves of a knight on a chessboard.

The [knights-tour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knights-tour) tag has twelve questions, most of them are unanswered and only three have more than 100 views. I think it would be better to replace this tag by the [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag, which seem to cover the whole knights-tour issue and is quite popular. 
The tag doesn't seem useful, questions I have had a look at don't seem any more helpful with this tag.

Comment: Twelve tags is trivial to handle, done.

Comment: It's only trivial to ninjas... low rep buddies (or Badda's if you like) may not be experienced enough for that.

Comment: Yep, it would have taken me a *(k)night*.

Comment: Not only you, others had to review your changes. So it was a good idea to let others (with > 2k reputation) do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding a knights tour is a classical combinatorial problem often used in the context of constraints. It has practically nothing to do with chess - except the board and the knight. Chess is much more complex.

Nobody who is searching for [chess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chess) has any use of knight's tours and vice versa. So please @MartijnPieters undo these changes.

Comment: Out of the twelve questions tagged `knights-tour` nearly four of them were actually on the classical combinatorial problem. Not saying this is enough to burn the tag, but it shows that it is not correctly used

Comment: Feel free to remove the chess tags from those 12 I edited, but I don't think those posts needed a distinct tag. One of them was about 'nightwatchjs', not sure how that post ended up with the tag.. See my [revision activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Comment: I've moved the 11 questions that were actually about using the knight-moves technique to use the [tag:combinatorics] tag instead; [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bcombinatorics%5d%20knights%20is%3aq) lists them all, so easy enough to update if someone wants to do further clean-up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So is it now ok to still use the tag knights-tour or not?

Comment: @false I think the `combinatorics` has been considered as more relevant instead of creating and using the `knights-tour` only for a few posts.

Comment: @false: I don't think that the technique is unique enough to warrant its own tag. Do you feel there are experts looking to use it to track questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, I saw those related to [tag:prolog]

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And, the tag combinatorics is not specific at all. Nobody will use this for searching. You could add this tag to any prolog-tagged post which uses backtracking e.g.

Comment: Interestingly, it's 2019 - there are 27 questions with this tag.  I'm still not convinced that this tag is useful.

Comment: That's twice as much as 2 years ago